# Dump one Double array and two Long arrays into ByteBuffer in Java

Tags: java, arrays, bytebuffer

I want to dump one Double array and two Long arrays into a bytebuffer. I could use a loop and do

```
double[] arr1 = new double[size];
long[] arr2 = new long[size];
long[] arr3 = new long[size];
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    buffer.putDouble(arr1[i]);
    buffer.putLong(arr2[i]);
    buffer.putLong(arr3[i]);
}
```

This doesn't seem efficient. Is there a way to balk dump them?

Comment: If I were you, I'd measure the throughput on your typical inputs before assuming that this is too slow.

Comment: You're not "bulk-dumping" them, you're interleaving the data. And there isn't anything in the JDK that knows how you want to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly want to "bulk dump" the data, rather than interleave it in some application-dependent manner, then you can create `LongBuffer` and `DoubleBuffer` views into your `ByteBuffer`. The general procedure is as follows:

1. Call `position()` to set the position of the buffer to wherever you want to store the array (you'll have to calculate this based on the size of the primitives).
2. Call `slice()` on the buffer to create a new buffer that shares the backing store but is offset.
3. Call `asLongBuffer()` or `asDouble()` buffer on the new buffer.
4. Call the bulk `put()` method on the buffer created in step 3.

This process is a convenience, *not* a performance enhancement. Unless you're talking tens of millions of elements, you're unlikely to see any improvement at all, and even then you're probably looking at microseconds.